# Word for "creating laughter"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a literary word which means "to create laughter". Is there such a word in English?

I'm going to use this word in the following title:

> Philosophical Theories of "Creating Laughter" and Study of Adaptive Samples of His Humor

Comment: Any other word/ phrase/ term/ neologism may not convey the meaning as directly and unambiguously as it is now. Your proposed title is fine as I see it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A commonly-used term for this is *[risible](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/risible)*, with senses including

> 1. Of or pertaining to laughter
> 2. Provoking laughter; ludicrous; ridiculous; humorously insignificant
> 3. (of a person) Easily laughing; prone to laughter

The first part of the title you're considering would read "Philosophical Theories of Risibility".  (I don't know what you mean in the second part of the title.)

Comment: Sounds an absolutely good word for me.

Comment: Sounds like **funny, mirthful, laughable, hilarious, amusing** are not literary words. Strange to me :D As far as I know literary is not equal of Latin ;-)

Comment: Does risible have a negative connotation? Longman defines: something that is risible is so stupid that it deserves to be laughed at  [SYN  ridiculous].

Comment: Manoochehr has second thoughts. Yes, *risible* relates to *laughable* as well, so beware. Syn.: ludicrous, ridiculous, laughable, comical, funny. []

Comment: In the 1800's when "risibility" was a [relatively popular word](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=risibility&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=0), "risible" was understood to mean "having the power to create laughter", and, by extension, "creating laughter". "Risibility", however, was understood to mean not "creating laughter" but "the quality of laughing". [A critical pronouncing dictionary](http://books.google.com/books?id=VqURAAAAIAAJ&dq=%22risibility%22&pg=PA720#v=onepage&q=%22risibility%22&f=false)

Answer (score 4):

I think these (risibility, humorousness) words are not so usable because the humor is always two-sided thing. You can't make a joke that would be funny for everybody. Even more, jokes are very rarely funny for really broad public. Children jokes are a bit more universal, but they are for children only. The jokes for elder public highly depend on the culture and the place of the listener in it.

Because of that the word humor is used instead. It supposes the sense of humor on both sides.

So, why not Philosophical Theories of Humor instead? You won't be risible with such title :-)

Comment: good to point out!

Answer (score 1):

I think "humorousness" might be another option  "Philosophical Theories of Humorousness" sounds good to me and the word is much more common even in the other than English speaking countries